# How to access settings (SharedPreferences?) in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have a file `res/xml/preferences.xml` with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="pref_key_development_settings"
        android:title="@string/pref_development_title">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="10.0.0.160/webservice"
            android:key="pref_webservice"
            android:summary="@string/pref_webservice_summary"
            android:title="@string/pref_webservice_title" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

How do I access `pref_webservice` from an Activity?

I've tried these, and they do not work (it defaults to the second parameter as I presume it can't find the key):

```
SharedPreferences prefMan = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
String spString = prefMan.getString("pref_webservice", "null");

SharedPreferences prefMan = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String spString = prefMan.getString("pref_webservice", "null");
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to specify that preferences.xml is a shared preferences file somewhere??

### EDIT

Figured it out. I was missing `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);`

Comment: check keyset that contains "pref_webservice"

Comment: Did you edit the preference before trying to read it?

Comment: Fixed - answer in the edit above.